# Mala interpretación de etiquetas HTML dentro de un archivo Blade de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Dentro de un proyecto de Laravel, estoy implementando un envío de email simple a través de una clase Mailable.

A modo de pruebas, estoy iniciando el envío desde el archivo de rutas "./routes/web.php" así:

```
use App\Mail\TestMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

Route::get('/ejemplo-mailer', function () {
    //return view('welcome');

    $smtpAbbrevUnico = 'MTp';

    $emailTo = 'pep@este.es';
    $saludoEspecial = ' ... OKiDOKi' . "-$smtpAbbrevUnico";

    $objEmailData = new \stdClass();
    $objEmailData->to_nombre = 'Pep' . "-$smtpAbbrevUnico";
    $objEmailData->msg_respuesta = "Hola:

¿Cómo te va? Espero que lo pases bien en tu cumpleaños.
Vuelve pronto.

Saludos.$saludoEspecial";
    $objEmailData->from_nombre = env('APP_NAME', 'XXXX');

    //Devolver una respuesta de que se envió el correo o NO
    try {
        //Envío predeterminado por MailTrap
        ////Mail::to($emailTo)->send(new TestMail($objEmailData));
        Mail::mailer('smtp')->to($emailTo)->send(new TestMail($objEmailData));
        echo 'Email de respuesta enviado'. $saludoEspecial;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "ERROR-$smtpAbbrevUnico:: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
});
```

A través de la Facade de Mail, se envían el objeto de datos a la clase Mailable correspondiente, en este caso, a TestMail que tiene este contenido:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TestMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The objResponseData object instance.
     *
     * @var ObjResponseData
     */
    public $objEmailData;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($objEmailData)
    {
        $this->objEmailData = $objEmailData;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.testmail_web')
                    ->text('emails.testmail_plain');
    }
}
```

Finalmente, a través del método `build()` de `TestMail`, se instauran las vistas que servirán de plantilla a la hora de construir el email a enviar.

Todo llega a la bandeja de correo correspondiente, en este caso a una de pruebas de MailTrap.
El problema es que la versión web del correo no llega bien formateada a HTML. En concreto, el contenido referente a lo que sería el típico contenido insertado a través de un TextArea, con sus saltos de línea.
En este caso, el texto que queda guardado dentro de `$objEmailData->msg_respuesta` debería llegar al correo respetando todos los saltos de línea.

Debería llegar así:

> Hola:
>
> ¿Cómo te va? Espero que lo pases bien en tu cumpleaños. Vuelve pronto.
>
> Saludos. ... OKiDOKi-MTp

pero llega en una única línea sin respetar los saltos de línea introducidos inicialmente antes de enviar el correo:

> Hola: ¿Cómo te va? Espero que lo pases bien en tu cumpleaños. Vuelve pronto. Saludos. ... OKiDOKi-MTp

Entonces, sabiendo que los saltos de línea en un textarea o al teclear código directamente, internamente, son un "`\n`" y no un "`<br>`", he querido reemplazar una cosa por la otra en la variable correspondiente tal que así:

```
$objEmailData->msg_respuesta = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $objEmailData->msg_respuesta);
```

Entonces, el correo llega con sus `br` pero imprimidos como si fuera texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto se ve de esta forma porque, internamente, si se visiona la fuente HTML del correo, el texto aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También, en vez de emplear el `str_replace()`, he utilizado el `nl2br()` reemplazando, igualmente, los `\n` por `<br>` pero, luego, llegando no formateados como etiquetas HTML.

En este momento, tras observar esto, he querido aplicar alguna otra cosa para transformar el `&lt;br&gt;` en `<br>`.
Algo como aplicar esto:

```
$objEmailData->msg_respuesta = htmlspecialchars_decode(nl2br($objEmailData->msg_respuesta));
```

Pero, el resultado es el mismo. Entonces, espero que alguien me aconseje como llegar a resolver esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale:

Ya me acordé de cómo solucionar el problema que he planteado. Se me había olvidado por llegar algo de tiempo no programando al detalle en Laravel.

Bueno, según lo que se comenta en el apartado "Displaying Unescaped Data" de la sección de "[Displaying Data](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data)" del capítulo de "Blade Templates" de la documentación de Laravel, resulta que, "De manera predeterminada, las declaraciónes "{{ }}" de Blade son enviadas mediante la función htmlspecialchars de PHP para prevenir ataques XSS. Si no deseas que tu información sea escapada, puedes utilizar la siguiente sintáxis:"

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Por tanto, para mi caso, todo se soluciona con esto que sigue (primero, reemplazo los "\n" por `<br>` y luego lo imprimo):

```
Hello, {!! nl2br($objEmailData->msg_respuesta) !!}.
```

Y, con eso, ya llega el texto del mensaje en el formato apropiado en la versión HTML, con sus `<br>` correspondientes, dentro del contenido del correo recibido.

Para todo al que le pueda servir ...

Saludos.